# How to integrate something already having integration.

Tags: integration

The textbook wrote,

\begin{align}
g_n(t)&=\int_0^tf(t-s)g_{n-1}(s)ds, &n=2, 3, \cdots, &&0 \le t \le \infty \\
G_n(t)&=\int_0^tF(t-s)dG_{n-1}(s), &n=2, 3, \cdots, &&0 \le t \le \infty
\end{align}

Can someone explain above step by step?
I am not sure it is okay that just integral $f(t-s)$.

---

if $f(t-s)=t-s$ and $g_{n-1}(s)=s$,
$$
g_n(t)=\int_0^tts-s^2ds=\left[{\frac{ts^2}{2}-\frac{s^3}{3}}\right]_0^t=\frac{t^3}{6}\\
\therefore G_n(t)=\int_0^t\frac{t^3}{6}dt=\frac{t^4}{24}\\\\
$$
however, if I tried like the textbook (textbook said that below equation can be gotten by integrating upper equation.

$$
G_n(t)=\int_0^t F(t-s) dG_{n-1}(s)=\int_0^t \frac{(t-s)^2}{2}d\left(\frac{s^2}{2}\right)=\int_0^t \frac{(t-s)^2}{2}sds=\int_0^t \frac{t^2s-2ts^2+s^3}{2} ds = \left[{\frac{t^2s^2}{4}-\frac{ts^3}{3}+\frac{s^4}{8}}\right]_0^t=\frac{1}{24}t^4
$$

Hmm, astonishingly, the result are same!

---

However, if $f(t-s)=3$ and $g_{n-1}(s)=4$,
$$
g_n(t)=\int_0^t 12 ds=12t\\
\therefore G_n(t)=\int_0^t12tdt=6t^2\\
$$
$$
G_n(t)=\int_0^t F(t-s) dG_{n-1}(s)=\int_0^t3(t-s)d(4s)=\int_0^t3(t-s)4ds=12\int_0^t(t-s)ds=\left[-6(t-s)^2\right]_0^t=6t^2
$$

Comment: I see no contradictory. Try to let $f(t-s)=t-s$ (i.e. $f(x)=x$) and $g_0=1$ and calculate $g_1$, $g_2$, and so on and you will see it is not a problem.

Comment: the domain of integral has $t$. Is it fine if I ignore it? just consider $f(t-s)$?

Comment: Since you integrate with respect to $s$ it is not a problem to have $t$ in the limit of integration. Your integrals are convolution integrals, often connected with Laplace transforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to integrate something already having integration.

The LHS (left hand side of the equation) of both formulas feature the $n$-th elment of a series of functions, the RHS (right hand side of the equation) the $n-1$-th, so it is not necessarily a case of the same function showing up on the LHS and RHS.

> \begin{align}
>  \color{blue}{g_n(t)}&=\int_0^tf(t-s)\color{blue}{g_{n-1}(s)}ds, &n=2,
>  3, \cdots, &&0 \le t \le \infty \\
>  \color{blue}{G_n(t)}&=\int_0^tF(t-s)d\color{blue}{G_{n-1}(s)}, &n=2,
>  3, \cdots, &&0 \le t \le \infty \end{align}

On the other hand nothing speaks against a function showing up both as result and as integrand. E.g.
$$
f(t) = \int\limits_0^t f(\tau) \, d\tau
$$

There might be solutions for such an integral equation or not, just as for any differential equation or any equation in general.

Comment: Hmm.. sorry I don't understand what you are talking about because of my short knowledge. although you answered for me, Sorry.

Comment: I updated the answer. Is this clearer?

Comment: I have to think more :( So bad head :( Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out this $G_n(t)$.
Thank you all for your hints.

\begin{align}
G_n(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^t g_n(\tau)~d\tau \\
&= \int_{\tau=0}^t \int_{s=0}^\tau { f(\tau-s) \cdot g_{n-1}(s) } ~ds ~d\tau \\
&= \int_{s=0}^t \int_{\tau=s}^t { f(\tau-s) \cdot g_{n-1}(s) } ~d\tau ~ds \\
&= \int_{s=0}^t \left( \int_{\tau=s}^t { f(\tau-s) } ~d\tau \right) \cdot g_{n-1}(s) ~ds \\
&= \int_0^t { \left[F(t-s) - F(0)\right] } \cdot g_{n-1}(s) ~ds \\
&= \int_0^t { F(t-s) } \cdot g_{n-1}(s) ~ds \\
&= \int_0^t { F(t-s) } ~dG_{n-1}(s) \\
\end{align}